# Sending data from angular to express nodejs server running on different domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ngcordova

So I am trying to send some data I have in angular to my nodejs server. Let me start with my code:
index.html

```html
<body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
        </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <form>
                <input type="text" ng-model="message">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()">
            </form>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Here is a text box with data, then the submit button will send the message and deviceID to the server.

app.js

```html
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var devToken;
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
          "debug": true
      });
      push.register(function(token) {
          devToken = token;
          console.log("Device token:", token.token);
      });
    
    $scope.submit = function() {
        
        var message = "Hello";
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 
            token: devToken,
            message: message
            
        })
    }
})
```

As you can see, I am trying to grab a message and the deviceID and post it to my express server.

server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var apns = require('apns');
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

var app = express();

var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaS.........plD2s8');

var registrationTokens = [];
registrationTokens.push('Insert Device ID here that is passed from app.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("DEVICE ID == " + req.body.devToken);
    sender.send("Hello", { registrationTokens: registrationTokens });
    
})

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('running on port 8080');
});
```

SO to recap, I am needing help getting my data when submitted to be available on my nodejs express server (which runs at a different domain/port than the Angular app). Can anyone help me figure out how to get my data from angular to express nodejs? Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a route to capture the post:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    ...
});
```

Then the front end could pass whatever you want

```
    $http.post("/", {message:message, devToken:devToken}).success(function(message, status) {
        console.log('Message posted');
    })
```

If the backend is not on the same origin as the OP states in the comments, you would need to enable cross origin requests.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
```

Note: don't use * for production unless really want to allow requests from anywhere.

Comment: I just edited to that and I am still getting "Cannot GET /" message at localhost:8080. What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing the message  "running on port 8080" in your console when you start the app?

Comment: Yes I do when i run server.js.

Comment: is that app.post that you replied in the server.js or app.js?

Comment: So if you just hit localhost:8080 in your browser, you get that message in the browser? I would expect that you would also see an error in your server console because you route for the get is trying to access req.body.devToken and in your get req.body is probably null or undefined.

Comment: Your front end should be doing a post to your backend... and that app.post goes in your backend server.js to handle that request

Comment: Yes I get that in the browser. There are no errors in the console. Its very perplexing. I am very confused on why it won't go through even though I am posting in the server and sending a post in app.js

Comment: Is your index.htm page being served from that same server app? If not, and it is running on a server at a different host or port, it won't be able to hit it because your backend isnt set up to allow cross origin requests. Are you seeing anything else in your browser console?

Comment: SO I am using ionic to run my app. I am running ionic serve in my browser at http://192.168.1.2:8100. And when I hit submit on the page it needs to send the data to my express node server which is running at localhost:8080. I am guessing that is my issue? Do you know what to do differently?

Comment: Awesome. Ill check that out. Thanks for your help. Ill message back if I come across something else. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright so I added it to my app.js and did some research on cors but it still doesn't seem to be working. I have to be doing something wrong obviously. Any ideas man?

Comment: I got it. So look at my app.js changes. It works. Except now I don't know how to send my devToken and message to server.js. It communicates though!

Comment: The second argument to $http.post () is the data you are passing. If you pass an object in there, that should basically be the req.body object in your server's route handler function.

Comment: Not exactly. $http can be used in two ways. The first is the way you are doing it but the data you want send to the server should be nested as an object in the data property.... {method:"...", url: "...", data: {message: "...", devToken}}. The second way is to use the shortcut method as i did in my answer. See the docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: Got the token and message to be sent to server correctly. Thanks for your help! just came across another issue that is irrelevant to post, trying to send push notifications to device. Thanks for your help. you've been fantastic